# timing a python function timeit vs time.clock disparity

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, timeit

```
import time
import logging
from functools import reduce

logging.basicConfig(filename='debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)



def read_large_file(file_object):
    """Uses a generator to read a large file lazily"""

    while True:
        data = file_object.readline()
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


def process_file_1(file_path):
    """Opens a large file and reads it in"""

    try:
        with open(file_path) as fp:
            for line in read_large_file(fp):
                logging.debug(line)
                pass

    except(IOError, OSError):
        print('Error Opening or Processing file')


def process_file_2(file_path):
    """Opens a large file and reads it in"""

    try:
        with open(path) as file_handler:
            while True:
                logging.debug(next(file_handler))
    except (IOError, OSError):
        print("Error opening / processing file")
    except StopIteration:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "TB_data_dictionary_2016-04-15.csv"

    l1 = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        start = time.clock()
        process_file_1(path)
        end = time.clock()
        diff = (end - start)
        l1.append(diff)

    avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l1) / len(l1)
    print('processing time (with generators) {}'.format(avg))


    l2 = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        start = time.clock()
        process_file_2(path)
        end = time.clock()
        diff = (end - start)
        l2.append(diff)

    avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l2) / len(l2)
    print('processing time (with iterators) {}'.format(avg))
```

Output of the program:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/pypen/data_structures/generators/generators1.py
processing time (with generators) 0.028033358176432314
processing time (with iterators) 0.02699498330810426
```

Another approach that I used is as follows.

```
def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "TB_data_dictionary_2016-04-15.csv"

    wrapped = wrapper(process_file_1, path)
    t = timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=100)
    print('processing time (with generators) {}'.format(t))

    wrapped = wrapper(process_file_2, path)
    t = timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=100)
    print('processing time (with iterators) {}'.format(t))
```

This gives me a different result.

```
 C:\Python34\python.exe C:/pypen/data_structures/generators/generators1.py
    processing time (with generators) 3.0999817624283916
    processing time (with iterators) 3.2149597826018304
```

I would expect the implementation that uses `generators` to be faster than the one that uses `iterators` (which is what I am getting when I use timeit).

Why am I not getting the same result using the other method.

Comment: Why aren't you just for-looping over the file object directly? You've timed two bad ways to do a thing, but not the natural way to do it.

Comment: @user2357112  - can you please eloberate?

Comment: `with open(path) as f:` `for line in f:` `logging.debug(line)`

Comment: @user2357112 - I am trying to measure time take by a generator object vs iteratror object

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're completely misunderstanding what generators and iterators are. A generator is a kind of iterator. Your `process_file_1` is wrapping an unnecessary extra generator around the file object (which is an iterator), while your `process_file_2` is using the iterator protocol in an unnecessarily awkward and manual way to retrieve lines from the file object.

Comment: @user2357112 -mmm :(  I got this from this tutorial. http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/27/python-201- an-intro-to-generators/ . Please let me know your thoughts. thanks

Comment: Yeah, that article is pretty awful. Ignore it.

Comment: @user2357112 - I am looking for a good example that differentiate between iterators and generatros. Could you point me to one?

Comment: Generators are just a kind of iterator. Anything you can do with iterators in general, you can do with a generator. Generators can also be written to use a different form of interaction with `send`, but that's a specialized, uncommon use.